# Plotting confidence interval of multilevel logistic regression with y in OR

Tags: logistic, confidence-interval, data-visualization, stata

In my analysis, sickness (y, binary) was regressed against pollution (x, continuous) and other confounders, using multilevel logistic regression (mcghermite in Stata). I obtained the coefficient of x, (b) and its SE & 95% CI.

```
ln[y/(1-y)]=a+bx+e
```

Ultimately, my goal is to plot a dose-response curve between the odds ratio of y against x, using the regression results. The equation of my regression line to be plotted is:

```
OR(y)= exp(b*x)
```

Setting x=0 as the reference point for OR.

Where I'm lost is in plotting the 95% CI of my regression line. My questions are:

1. What is the equation of the 95% CI lines? Is it simple enough for me to compute, or is there Stata code I can use?
2. Is the CI line different from OR(y)=exp(UpperCI_b*x)?
3. Would my regression line confidence interval be non-existent at the reference point (x=0) and broaden as x increases?

Comment: I have never heard of `mcghermite`. Do you mean `melogit` or `meqrlogit`? If so, take a look at the `margins` and `marginsplot` commands.